# How can i interate on Fulfillment Messages to return message by message to client

Tags: c#, google-api, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I'm using Dialogflow to integrate on Microsoft Bot Framework, when i use FulfillmentText, my code works fine, but i need to use FulfillmentMessages because i have many messages returning on my code, i tried this code, but "retorno" variable receive json format return, how can i interate to all messages returning line by line to response for  my client?

```
foreach (Intent.Types.Message msg in queryResult.FulfillmentMessages)
{
   retorno = msg.Text;
   Console.WriteLine($"Fulfillment text: {retorno}");
}
```

Do you have any sample using Microsoft Bot Framework and Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.V2 API?

Answer (score 1):

I created a array of IActivity and used foreach at each messages adding text by text to "respostas" array.
Finally i used "await turnContext.SendActivitiesAsync(retorno, cancellationToken);" because i can pass array of IActivity:

```
                IActivity[] respostas;
                respostas = new IActivity[1];
                int cnt = 0;

                foreach (Intent.Types.Message msg in queryResult.FulfillmentMessages)
                {
                    foreach (string msgstr in msg.Text.Text_)
                    {                            
                        retorno = retorno + msgstr.ToString() + "\r\n";
                        respostas[cnt] = MessageFactory.Text(msgstr.ToString(), msgstr.ToString());
                        cnt++;
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine($"Fulfillment text: {retorno}");
                }
                await turnContext.SendActivitiesAsync(retorno, cancellationToken);
```

This code works fine for my objectives.